# Find a bijection $f:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1)$.

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I could see that similar questions have been asked, but I do want to come up with my own answer, so I haven't looked at any of them. I am acknowledging that and I am sorry if that breaks rules.

My thought was to use the sequence $(x_n)=1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{5}.....\frac{1}{n}$ and define the function as follows

$f(0)=0$ and $f(x_n)=x_{n+1}$.

After more thinking, I realize that this 'misses' a lot of numbers. Is this the right idea to begin with? If so, how could I improve it to make it work.

Comment: Yes, you have the right idea. Let $f:[0,1] \to [0,1)$ be defined as
$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x_{n+1}  & x=x_n\\
x & \text{else}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Oh that makes a lot of sense! and by still defining $f(0)=0$ the function is a bijection. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution. 
Consider the function

\begin{align}
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{ if }\ \  x= 1,\\
x+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}-S_n & \text{ if }\ \  S_n\leq x<S_{n+1}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
S_n = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\ldots +\frac{1}{2^n} \ \ \text{ and } \ \ S_0 = 0. 
\end{align}
It's probably easier to understand if you sketch the function.

Edit: Base on this construction, you could actually show that there exists a bijection between $[0, 1]$ and $[0, 1]\backslash\{x_1, \ldots, x_n, \ldots\}$, i.e. $[0, 1]$ with countably many points removed.