# Give a bijection between two sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

The two sets are the following: $(0,1) $ and $ [0,1]$

I know that (the cardinality of) $|(0,1)|=| \mathbb R|$ so it has to be true, that $[0,1]=| \mathbb R |$

Can I maybe use Hilbert's paradox of the Grand Hotel, or should I found a function, which Domain is $(0,1)$?

Comment: As reference, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2204690/find-a-bijection-f0-1-rightarrow0-1/2204720#2204720

Comment: If you know their cardinalities are both equal to $|\mathbb{R}|$, you can just compose the bijections which let you know this fact.

Comment: I know their cardinalities, but I can't prove it

Comment: Also, more or less everything on this page: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/160738

Comment: @AsafKaragila Oh my!  That *is* a popular question! :)